# ESLint Error 'Invalid count value' when run with --fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-formatting, eslint

I am having around 7000 lint error while running the lint test. But if I try to run it with `--fix` like below

```
> esw -c .eslintrc ./src '.js, .jsx' --color --fix
```

I am getting the following error

```
Invalid count value
RangeError: Invalid count value
    at String.repeat (native)
    at report (/Users/Projects/uni-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/indent.js:267:73)
    at checkLastReturnStatementLineIndent (/Users/Projects/uni-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/indent.js:430:17)
    at EventEmitter.ReturnStatement (/Users/Projects/uni-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/indent.js:1050:21)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/Users/Projects/uni-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:40:22)
    at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/Users/Projects/uni-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:608:23)
    at CommentEventGenerator.enterNode (/Users/Projects/uni-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/comment-event-generator.js:97:23)
    at Controller.enter (/Users/Projects/uniqlo-sh/fr-webapp/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:927:36)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved the issue.  If there is no blank line before the `return` statement in anywhere  in the code we will get this error message.

I have just put a blank line before the return statement the lint command with `--fix` is working without any issue

I changed the code like below

```
const { customErrors } = state.APIErrors;
return {
    ...state.cart,
    ...state.payment,
```

into

```
const { customErrors } = state.APIErrors;

return {
    ...state.cart,
    ...state.payment,
```

Comment: Adipoli japan kaara :p

Comment: @mshameer Can you please log this as an issue here, i think this needs to be fixed. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues

Comment: @Gyandeep Issue posted in github